# P0304 code on PT Cruiser

Tags: engine, chrysler, pt-cruiser, p0304

I have a 2005 PT Cruiser Convertible that's leaking oil in #4 cylinder causing engine light to come on.  Now, I have changed valve cover gasket and tube seals, spark plugs and wires and coil, pcv checked okay, compression test on all cylinder was 120.

Still leaks in #4 and light comes on with code 304.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the leak in #4 cylinder?  If the compression test showed all the same what leak are you referring to?  You mention a code 304, is that a P0304 or another type of code?  How did you pull the code?

Comment: The P0304 code and any oil leakage will most likely be two different issues. If you put a new sparkplug in and it didn't change how it's running, the issue isn't with any possible oil leak. How did you determine there is an oil leak?

Comment: oil leaking in #4 cylinder,Sorry all the codes start with P0,so it is P0304,misfire in #4 cyl. Pulled plug ,dripping oil off plug.Turn the key three times then gives code,also Auto Zone

Answer (score 1):

From [obd-codes.com](https://www.obd-codes.com/p0304):

> A P0304 code means that the the car's computer has detected that one of the engine's cylinders is not firing properly. In this case it's cylinder #4.
>
> A code P0304 may mean that one or more of the following has happened:
>
> - Faulty spark plug or wire
> - Faulty coil (pack)
> - Faulty oxygen sensor(s)
> - Faulty fuel injector
> - Burned exhaust valve
> - Faulty catalytic converter(s)
> - Running out of fuel
> - Poor compression
> - Defective computer

I would recommend checking compression on your 4th cylinder.  If it's really bad, it not impossible a bit of oil is seeping in there.  It could be time for a piston ring replacement.